# Distributing from frequency table to original data?

Tags: r, database

I have a data_aa as below

```
ID x.cal tx.cal 
1    0    0 
2    0    0
3    0    0
4    0    0
5    1    1
6    10   1
7    10   1
8    11   1
9    11   1
```

With above data_aa, I made a frequency table as below and got an result_A variable.

```
x.cal  tx.cal   frequency     result_A
0          0     3223        0.05268579
1          1      35         0.05048418
1          10     2          0.89475308
1          11     1          0.98251303
1          12     1          1.06831347
1          13     1          1.15179768
```

I want to add result_A value to my original data data_aa.
How I can redistribute result_A from frequency data to original data_aa ?

I want to add result_A value to each individual (ID) from frequency table. 
My desired table as below

```
ID x.cal tx.cal     result_A 
    1    0    0      0.05268579 
    2    0    0      0.05268579 
    3    0    0      0.05268579 
    4    0    0      0.05268579 
    5    1    1      0.05048418 
    6    10   1      0.89475308 
    7    10   1      0.89475308  
    8    11   1      0.98251303 
    9    11   1      0.98251303
```

Comment: What output do you want? What have you tried so far?

Comment: From frequency table I got an reqult_A. I want to redistribute result_A value to original (data_aa) by adjusting x.cal and tx.cal variables.

Comment: But HOW? Edit your question and add desired result.

Comment: Try something like `data_aa <- merge(data_aa, df2, by = c("x.cal, "tx.cal"), all.x = T)`, where `df2` is your aggregated table (didn't test that code though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use David's approach to combine the dataframes, then clean the resultant to get the format you want.

```
df <- merge(data_aa, freq_aa, by = c("x.cal", "tx.cal"), all.x = T)

result <- df[c("ID", "x.cal", "tx.cal", "result_A")]
```